# Any similar usage for "require" (Angular js) in Angular 5

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade

We are facing an issue while doing the migration from AngularJS to Angular 5 by using **ngUpgrade** module

Below is the code snippet:

```
class abcController{
   //some instructions
}

const abcDefination = {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: {
        parent: '^test1',
        parentCard: '?^test2Component'
    },
    bindings: {
        type: "@",
        dataitem: "<"
    },
    template: require('./template.html'),
    controller: abcController
};
```

How to use/any equivalent usage for **"require"** in angular 5 ??

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: you can use `import`

Comment: Are you asking about the `require` property of the component definition or the `require` function in the `template` property? "facing an issue" is even more vague than "not working". Please describe the problem behavior. Is there error message?

Comment: @georgeawg `require` property of the component definition. there is no error message, want to know how to use that `require` property in angular 5. As we are migrating from Angular JS to Angular by using the ng-upgrade module.

Comment: @Pooja, I know its way too late to post an answer. But this is more of a question ? Did converting an angular component to ES6 based moudle and then importing it work ? I am kinda in the same grounds now ? or did u get  any solution ?

Comment: @littleanimboy yes, converting an angular component to ES6 based module and then importing worked